# can't set variable itself with getters and setters in swift

Tags: swift, properties, getter-setter

I was doing one example on getters and setters the example is below

```
import Foundation

class person
{
    var first_name:String
    {
        get
        {
           return self.first_name
        }
        set
        {
            if (newValue.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits) != nil){
                print("please enter valid name")
            }
            else
            {
                self.first_name = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}

let person1 = person.init()
person1.first_name = "rahul"
```

but this gives me error
but when I do this example

```
import Foundation

class person
{
    var name = ""
    var first_name:String
    {
        get
        {
            return name
        }
        set
        {
            if (newValue.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits) != nil){
                print("please enter valid name")
            }
            else
            {
                name = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}

let person1 = person.init()
person1.first_name = "rahul"
print(person1.first_name)
```

it runs and gives me output so my question is if I am using getter and setter then why I can't get or set the variable it self like I have done in above example so can any one explains me what is going on here

Comment: "but this gives me error but when I do this example" what error?

Comment: In your first example you have a *computed property* with a getter and a setter which *call themselves recursively* ... 

Comment: You should use struct instead of class and just create a fallible initializer. `struct Person {
    let name: String ; 
    init?(name: String) {
        guard name.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits) == nil else { return nil } ; 
        self.name = name
    }
}`

Comment: So when initialising your Person object `if let person = Person(name: "Rahul GUsai") {
    print(person.name)   // "Rahul GUsai\n"
} else {
    print("please enter valid name")
}`

Comment: You can also add some computed properties to your Person struct to add functionality like extracting the familyName or givename from the person's name `extension Person {
    var personNameComponents: PersonNameComponents? { return PersonNameComponentsFormatter().personNameComponents(from: name) }
    var givenName: String? { return personNameComponents?.givenName }
    var familyName: String? { return personNameComponents?.familyName }
}`

Comment: `if let person = Person(name: "Rahul GUsai") {
    print(person.familyName)   // "GUsai\n"
    print(person.givenName)   // "Rahul\n"
} else {
    print("please enter valid name")
}`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, suppose I'm setting the `first_name` property. So I call its setter. The setter makes sure the string is valid, and then calls:

```
self.first_name = newValue
```

This invokes `first_name`'s setter. The string is still valid, so the setter calls:

```
self.first_name = newValue
```

This invokes `first_name`'s setter. The string is still valid, so the setter calls:

```
self.first_name = newValue
```

and the cycle continues

By now you see the problem. This will go on forever until the program crashes due to too much recursion; you can't have the getter and setter call themselves like this. Instead, make a separate `private var _first_name` property, and have `first_name`'s getter and setter access that.